# Oracle wants me to use a Long instead of a CLOB

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pdo

TLDR: Oracle says I can only bind a LONG value for insert into a LONG column... but the column is a CLOB, which I believe should be able to handle a value of this size.

I have a table with a CLOB column:

```sql
  CREATE TABLE "WEB"."DATA_EXPLORER_QUERIES" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USER_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATE_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAST_RUN" DATE DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "RUNS" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(2500 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SLUG" VARCHAR2(2500 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SQL" CLOB NOT NULL ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" 
 LOB ("SQL") STORE AS SECUREFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192
  NOCACHE NOLOGGING  NOCOMPRESS  KEEP_DUPLICATES 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 106496 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ;
```

I'm trying to insert some data via PHP:

```php
$q = $pdo_internal->prepare("insert into data_explorer_queries (id, user_id, create_date, last_run, runs, title, slug, sql) values (?, ?, sysdate, sysdate, 1, ?, ?, ?)");
$q->execute([
    $id,
    $_SESSION['user_id'],
    $_POST['title'],
    $modified_slug,
    $_POST['sql']
]);
```

Here's a `var_dump` of the data:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '5' (length=1)
  1 => string '1078' (length=4)
  2 => string 'test' (length=4)
  3 => string 'test' (length=4)
  4 => string 'select
ziplist.n,
sz.zip,
round((nvl(sz.home_count,0) + nvl(sz.apt_count,0)) * .01515) as census_average
from standard_zip sz
inner join (
select 1 as n, 59421 as zip from dual
union all select 2 as n, 83213 as zip from dual
union all select 3 as n, 59201 as zip from dual
union all select 4 as n, 89001 as zip from dual
union all select 5 as n, 59410 as zip from dual
union all select 6 as n, 83128 as zip from dual
union all select 7 as n, 59937 as zip from dual
union all select 8 as n, 84021 as '... (length=22066)
```

This throws the following exception:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1461 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

Interestingly, when I open SQLDeveloper and double click on any value in the CLOB column in that table, I am able to paste this long string in and save it via the UI. Apparently this is only an issue when using PHP/PDO.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200534/pdo-oci-into-a-clob-field) if it helps you

Comment: I don't know PHP/PDO so I won't be able to help you; but let's make sure you understand the issue (I can't tell from the way you phrased your question). Oracle doesn't want you to use a LONG. It believes that you are giving it a LONG value, which it must save in a CLOB column - and it is telling you that LONG values can only be stored in LONG columns. So, make sure you are hunting for the right thing: Why does Oracle think it's being passed a LONG value, when your intent was to pass a CLOB. Something is getting in the middle and doing something you didn't expect.

Comment: @mathguy - Semantics. There is no meaningful difference between a Long value and a CLOB value until those values are stored in the database. The column definition is what's relevant here.

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou - That's what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I mark this as a duplicate I'll leave an answer here for convenience. (Credit to [Dimitris Filippou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68652808/oracle-wants-me-to-use-a-long-instead-of-a-clob/68654219#comment121328406_68652808))

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36200827/1444609), [PHP Bug #57095](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57095) indicates that inserting CLOB values does not work as expected when passing parameters to the `execute` method.

The workaround is use [`bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and specify the CLOB type as a string, and include the 4th parameter to indicate the string size for the CLOB value.

My updated, working code:

```php
$q = $pdo_internal->prepare("insert into data_explorer_queries (id, user_id, create_date, last_run, runs, title, slug, sql) values (?, ?, sysdate, sysdate, 1, ?, ?, ?)");
$q->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindParam(2, $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindParam(3, $_POST['title']);
$q->bindParam(4, $modified_slug);
$q->bindParam(5, $_POST['sql'], PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($_POST['sql']));
$q->execute();
```